# Devise locales pointing to previous release path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, capistrano, rails-i18n

I am getting

```
An I18n::InvalidLocaleData occurred in users#social_sign_in:

  can not load translations from /home/releases/20190221131459/config/locales/devise.en.yml: #<Errno::ENOENT: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /home/releases/20190221131459/config/locales/devise.en.yml>
  i18n (0.7.0) lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:184:in `rescue in load_yml'
```

The path which is being referred is wrong. My current release is `20190330184001`

```
capistrano (2.15.9, 2.15.7)
capistrano-ext (1.2.1)
capistrano-resque (0.2.2, 0.1.0)
capistrano-unicorn (0.2.0)
rvm-capistrano (1.5.6)
```

Also there are multiple folders in my releases folder. is this issue is regarding Capistrano or I18n gem..?

Comment: Are you restarting your application server after deploying the new version? This looks like either the application server or the background worker is still running an old version of the code.